# Save current directory between docker exec commands

Tags: docker, sh, exec, docker-exec

I have a list of commands which I need to issue one by one to a running docker container. However, when I "cd" in the container, it's not working as expected. For example:

```sh
docker run -di --name example alpine:latest

for CMD in 'mkdir -p example && touch example/file' 'cd example' 'ls'
do
  docker exec -w='/root' example sh -c "$CMD"
done
```

Will printout `example` instead of `file`. How should I properly execute series of statements, but preserving the working directory between their execution? Preferably, if it possible to do this without concatenating all the commands?

Comment: any need of running these command inside for loop? you can simple run `docker run -di --name example alpine:latest && docker exec -w='/root' example sh -c "mkdir -p example; touch example/file; cd example ; ls"` and this will print `file` as you are expecting.

Comment: @Adiii I'm aware of workarounds. Though I wonder if it's possible to navigate between states. I'm actually loading list of commands from yaml file, and executing them with `docker exec`. But any series of commands that contain `cd` will fail. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this, without parsing each command, and dynamically changing the workdir, or without concatenating commands.

Comment: can give minimal example where `cd` will fail? and what do you mean by `dynamically changing the workdir`? when you pass ` -w='/root'` it will run this `'/root'` directory

Comment: I meant parsing command for cd, and setting `-w` to new workdir before executing. `cd` won't fail as in fail to execute, but each new docker exec will have have workdir set to it's default. I wondered if there is a away to avoid concatenating commands, that's all.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Can you package this sequence of commands into a script to run, or better still, have a network-visible endpoint that can trigger this activity?  `docker exec` is a useful debugging tool but it’s not usually intended as the primary way you interact with a container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this format:

```
dingrui@gdcni:~/onie$ docker exec -w /root example sh -c 'mkdir -p example; touch example/file; cd example; ls'
file
```

or write these commands to a script and then mount it to container and run it in container:

```
dingrui@gdcni:~/onie$ docker run -itd -w /root -v $(pwd):/app --name example busybox /app/test.sh
12f7f2b55182bd18c45ce31e03390544adaedc1a2dd923d3bc4293b214301650
dingrui@gdcni:~/onie$ docker logs example 
file
```

Comment: It may be easier to concatenate all commands, and pass them as env var to container, and then run something like `docker exec <ID> 'sh -c eval "${SCRIPT}"'`